# IE Ajax Streaming/long-polling without folding the server

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, streaming, comet, long-polling

I'm trying to solve how to do Streaming for IE and long-polling without folding the server.  Here what I had in mind.

I 'll have a servlet called : TimeServlet.

in doGet or doPost() .. I'll suspend the request and send the time at each seconds.

```
....
suspend()

while(!stopped){
    request.writeln(new Date().toString());
}
```

or with a Scheduler and Runnable, but you get the point.

On the client in javascript I'll create a ajax connection.

My big questions are :

1 - How do I do streaming with IE ?  with Firefox and Chrome, I read the data when readyState==3, but in IE, the data is only available on readyState==4.

2 - How can I do long-polling in this example ?  Long-polling block until the server had data to push, but in this example, the server will always have something to push, so the client will do something like  while(true) and flood the server.  I suppose that I have to do something like that

ajax.push(null) ... on readyState==4 -> read ... after that setTimeout(resendRequest, 1);  //1 sec ?

there is someone that have a sample like that ?

my code works fine for FF and Chrome, but now I'm looking for IE and Opera.

EDIT

I found that I could use XDomainRequest in IE for streaming.  You have to have that in your server code :

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

I won't answer this question yet, because I don't know how to detect that the connection is completed.

with Ajax, it was easy.. ReadyState==4.  but I don't know for XDomainRequest.

I need to be able to trigger some javascript callback when the connection is closed.  Any ideas ?

Comment: I have never done comet in IE, but here is the object that allows you to get data as it is being received, [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx). The onprogress event should fire when data is transmitting and give you access. I've never tried so I can't help anymore than this, Sorry :/

Comment: thanks, but it's a little different than plain "Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" but will only works on state4.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Sebastien Yes it is different, but it is the only way to get access in IE8 or below, see [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/04/06/comet-streaming-in-internet-explorer-with-xmlhttprequest-and-xdomainrequest.aspx).

Comment: thanks Andrew. really nice web site.  I'll try that and post a response here with code

Comment: finally, at this point I'm not able to get it works.  I receive .onerror() event, not the text.  I used a post instead of get.   If I replace my URL for "http://www.enhanceie.com/test/streamWithPrelude.aspx?"+Math.random()   it will works.  I assume the problem could be in the server code.  can I see it in your example  ?

Comment: I been able to trace in my server code and it crash when I send some data in the response.  Need to figure out what it's causing the problem.  works fine when I send data and close the connection after that.. look like it's only when I send dummy data when I suspend the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to detect the close event.  You have to use the onload method.

So the code will look like that

```
var ajaxRequest = new XDomainRequest();


ajaxRequest.onload = function() { 
//alert("[XDR-onload]. responseText: " + ajaxRequest.responseText + ""); 
};

ajaxRequest.onerror = function() { alert("[XDR-onerror] Fatal Error."); };

ajaxRequest.ontimeout = function() { 
alert("[XDR-ontimeout] Timeout Error.");
};
ajaxRequest.onprogress = function() { 
//alert("[XDR-onprogress] responseText so far: " + ajaxRequest.responseText + "");
};
```

and don't forget to add the Header in the response (server's side)

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");